# Why doesn't "git branch --merged" report accurately?

Tags: git

Can anybody make sense of the following sequence of commands and output? What am I misunderstanding about the way Git works (or is this a bug in Git)?

```
sbuchanan@mage:~/projects/this$ git branch
  master
* release-2.7.0

sbuchanan@mage:~/projects/this$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.

sbuchanan@mage:~/projects/this$ git branch --merged master
  master

sbuchanan@mage:~/projects/this$ git branch --no-merged master
* release-2.7.0
```

The **master** branch is clearly already merged into **release-2.7.0** as you can see in the second command where I attempt to merge it again, and git responds that it's already up-to-date. I can manually confirm that the branches are indeed merged by looking at the Git log and the file contents of the repository.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`master` is clearly merged into `release-2.7.0` but not the other way around so `git branch --merged master` won't list `release-2.7.0` as `release-2.7.0` is not reachable from the tip of `master`.

From `git help branch`:

```
--merged [<commit>]
    Only list branches whose tips are reachable from the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the sense of `--merged` backward in my head. What I wanted was `--contains`.